# My renders keep having a lot of blur(unclear parts of the texure) how do I fix?

Tags: rendering

I have read several things on the forums and none of those work for me. The only thing i can have discovered that it is more clear in the far back.

[image: Image11]
https://we.tl/t-w5YoDknjxK

I have tried:

- Switching the samples a up and down
- F-Stop going up to 10
- Adding lights
- Putting off anti-allases
- Putting of minmap on user preferences
- Change the clippping Start up.
- Updating my CPU

Comment: HI. Please add some images to show your renders. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using de-noising? Often, de-noise values that are too high will cause blurriness and other related artifacts.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-uOHuDghxnA, its off

Comment: [Even if I don't have an answer, thanks for the improvements.] [Denoise settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsfKQ.png)

Comment: The Denoising helped a little, but still some texures of the blocks are kind of pushed toghether. Before: https://we.tl/t-cnwZcW5Rjv
After: https://we.tl/t-QlaRprEjkY